# How can I add a precision within 2 seconds c#

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering how I can add a precision of 2 seconds. At the moment my code works how i'd like but I'd like to add a precision of 2000 miliseseconds.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LocationNameSearch()
    {


// Create new stopwatch.
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing.
stopwatch.Start();

// Import the search method.


    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);



// Stop timing.
stopwatch.Stop();

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 3000, **2000**);


}
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear. What do you mean by adding a precision of 2000ms?

Comment: Do you mean that `ElapsedMilliseconds` is 2000 +- 2000 ms?

Comment: Ok what I mean is I want it to take less than 3 seconds which I can control. But I want a bit of leway. I could increase it to 5 seconds I suppose. That would solve the issue. Maybe I need a range. so if it's less than 3 seconds its a pass. If it's between 3-5 it throws a warning and above 5 it's a fail. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: @Peter: It does make sense but I don't necessarily think its a good idea. Unit tests should either pass or fail. They shouldn't have a "not sure" middle ground. Note that this is my view and I'm by no means a unit test expert. :)

Comment: As Chris said, the general view is that a Unit test should pass or fail, but you could make 2 tests, both calling the same test with a different threshold and name them such that the one indicates that it's not critical. That said, you could use `Assert.Inconclusive` to generate a warning : `if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000) Assert.Fail(); else if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 3000) Assert.Inconclusive();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to have a range of 2000 milliseconds over and under a specific value then you could use the following which checks if the elapsed milliseconds are within 2000 milliseconds of 3000.

```
Assert.IsTrue(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 3000 + 2000
              && stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000 - 2000
);
```

Edit: According to the comments it sounds like more of a differentation is needed:

```
if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000)
{
    if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000)
    {
         Assert.Fail("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        // Generate warning
        Assert.Fail("Warning");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. One question what I have is is this just the same as adding 5000 miliseconds?

Comment: One thing of note is that for the given code the second part of the logic (`>=3000-2000`) is redundant since with a thread.sleep 2000 I wouldn't expect it to ever be less then 1000. Also is it actually a problem if this code runs fast? It doesn't strike me that should be a failure condition...

Comment: Yeah if its between 0-3000 then it's passed 3000-5000 then it's a sign of issues potentially then 5000 plus it's a fail. If there's a way to capture these three areas that would be awesome. Just to note I will eventually be putting a method into where the sleep is. This is just to test the code initially.

Comment: @peter question is for just adding 5000 milliseconds yes correctly. hmmm sounds like you want in reality an if where you have 2 different things to do? (as assert itself knows only fail or success as far as I'm aware

Comment: @Peter I edited the answer so that it contains a differentation between 0-3000 (nothing to be done),  3000+ warning and possible error  and >5000 with error.

Comment: I think im going to use this one but remove the else as I don't need it to fail twice. So if I replaced the 5000 with another 3000 would that still make sense. I've seen 3001 passes 3002 fails.

Comment: you mean instead of >5000  >3000? then you should just use >3000 in the  first if

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the least  scale is `2000` then you should do this.

```
var lowprec = (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds/2000)*2000; // notice the integer division

if(lowprec < 3000)
{
    //pass
}
else if(lowprec < 5000)
{
    //warn
}
```

Here assume time elapsed is `3542` milliseconds. `lowprec` becomes `2000` (since its highest precision) and it will pass.

If time elapsed is `4032` milliseconds it `lowprec` becomes `4000` and then its warning.

But If i were you i would just compare results normally. in programming we dont have 50% true 50% false. it does not make sense. we only have 100% true or 100% false.

Comment: This is pretty awesome.

Comment: I see what you mean you don't want any ambiguity with the results. It's either Pass or Fail.

Comment: @Peter yeah. thats what i mean. i suggest you make precision `500` instead of `2000`. so it will only pass until `3499`. assuming the condition is `<= 3000`. but then again why not using `< 3500` straight? ;)